# Getting a property reference using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

```
var a = new obj();
var property = a.GetType().GetProperty("DB").GetValue(a,null) as testObject;
```

does this mean that the variable `property` hold a reference to the the same object that i got in object a , or a new testObject was made that holds the same values?

if this means creating a new object, then how can i get the reference to that property/backing field using reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`property` now holds a *referece* to whatever is in `a`'s `DB` property.

I'm not sure though what happens when you call `GetValue()` on a property that has a value type, I suppose you get a reference to a boxed copy of the original value, as explained in [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> Boxing a value type [to `object` in `GetValue()`'s case] allocates an object instance on the heap and copies the value into the new object.

Comment: i got confused because the function name is GetValue

Answer (score 2):

It means a value of a property `DB` of your object `a` cast to `testType` (you pass a reference to object `a` in `PropertyInfo.GetValue`), so there is only one object `a` and your variable references its `DB` property.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `property` holds reference to same value stored in property `DB`.

`GetValue(a,null)` return type is object so with as operator you are simple type casting it.