# Assign bool value to a property when name of that property is present in another array

Tags: c#

This is best I could make the question statement. Please be kind.

Here is the situation:

I have a string "InputValues" which contains values in comma seperated format: 
chkAwareness1,chkAwareness2,chkAwareness6,chkAwareness9,chkAwareness13...

I need to fill an object with bool value if the name matches with what I have in above string variable.

**example:
if InputValues contains "chkAwareness1" then "public bool chkAwareness1" should set to true, otherwise false.**

```
 public class SurveyCheckBox
    {
        public bool chkAwareness1 { get; set; }
        public bool chkAwareness2 { get; set; }
        public bool chkAwareness3 { get; set; }
        public bool chkAwareness4 { get; set; }
        public bool chkAwareness5 { get; set; }
        public bool chkAwareness6 { get; set; }
        public bool chkAwareness7 { get; set; }
                      .
                      .
                      .
   }

public void createObjectSurveyCheckBox(string InputValues)
{
    string[] ChkValues = InputValues.Split(',');
    SurveyCheckBox surveyChkBoxObj = new SurveyCheckBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPropertyInSurveyCheckBox ;i++ )
    { 
        // typeof(SurveyCheckBox).GetProperties()[i].Name
    }
}
```

I searched and I found GetProperties method through which I can get the name of property, but I am unable to figure out the logic.. how to search through the values and assign them to bool properties.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you write code that breaks silently(at runtime) if someone changes variable names? Instead use a single `Dictionary<string, bool>` or `Dictionary<int, bool>`.

Comment: these values are coming via http request from Angular app, I am receiving it in my webApi. Its an intranet app, and codechanges will be in my hand only. There are 63 checkboxes, values of which needs to be sent to Webapi, instead of sending object with 63 values. We just sent the names of those checkboxes which are checked.

Comment: there's no reason to write code that is unsafe, inefficient and not easy to maintain and understand anyway. You wouldn't use one table for each record in a database either, you would insert those records into the same table if they represent the same entity.

Comment: I agree, I will put this code for time being and think of a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. You just need to change your loop, really. The whole method should look like this:

```
public void CreateObjectSurveyCheckBox(string inputValues)
{
    string[] chkValues = inputValues.Split(',');
    SurveyCheckBox surveyChkBoxObj = new SurveyCheckBox();
    foreach (string value in chkValues)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(SurveyCheckBox).GetProperty(value);
        if (propInfo != null)
            propInfo.SetValue(surveyChkBoxObj, true);
    }
}
```

P.S. You'll notice I took the liberty of changing your capitalization to something much more standard. If you use capitalization like you had, you're likely to get lynched.

Comment: Thanks. This works as I wanted. I agree with Tim as well, the code is not good, will work with it for time being and look for better way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim; I would not use something like this in production code.

```
    public void createObjectSurveyCheckBox(string InputValues)
    {
        var instance = new SurveyCheckBox();

        foreach (var property in typeof(SurveyCheckBox).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("chkAwareness")))
        {
            if (InputValues.Contains(property.Name))
                property.SetValue(instance, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I agree, I will put this code for time being and think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the loop from the other direction, from 0 to MaxchkAwareness;
Sort the input first, before going into the loop.
You would also need an index to the next item in your input array (ChkValues), lets call that chkValueIndex;
If the next item in your input array, ChkValues[chkValueIndex], is "chkAwareness"+i.ToString()
then your property is true, and you increment your array pointer .
otherwise your property is false.
But I think you have to use reflection to set the properties in a loop like that, something like this:
[Getting a property reference using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871744/getting-a-property-reference-using-reflection)

I am sure there are better ways to restructure this and do it entirely different, but it sounds to me like you are trying to do the best you can with the system that was given you.

Comment: Nevermind, now I see itsme86's idea, that is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static void createObjectSurveyCheckBox(string InputValues)
{
    string[] ChkValues = InputValues.Split(',');
    SurveyCheckBox surveyChkBoxObj = new SurveyCheckBox();
    foreach (var prop in typeof(SurveyCheckBox).GetProperties())
    {
        if (ChkValues.Contains(prop.Name))
            prop.SetValue(surveyChkBoxObj, true);
    }
}
```